# Is there some kind of "package-search" function available for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, package, package-managers, emacs-helm

In Emacs, the `M-x` keybinding lets you search and execute available commands. I'm looking for a similar function/functionality that lets you search and install available packages from the Emacs repositories.

The best I can do at present is `M-x package-list-packages` followed by `C-s`, but this has a few shortcomings:

1. It requires that you navigate to the list of available packages, whereas I'd like something that works from most places within Emacs.
2. It only lets you cycle through the package list, whereas I'd like something that displays a narrowing list of results.
3. It doesn't support fuzzy matching (like Helm).

Does the functionality I'm looking for exist? Or is there a package that provides this functionality for Emacs? And if so, where can I find it?

Comment: Just use `M-x package-install` with `helm-mode` enabled

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like `M-x package-install` should do what you want. If you have `helm` installed, you will have a helm-like interface to search and install packages. Even without `helm`, it can be invoked from any buffer, it supports narrowing, and if you *do* have helm installed, it supports fuzzy matching.

I still tend to use `M-x package-list-packages` unless I know exactly what I am looking for, because unlike `package-install` it allows you to see details and descriptions of the packages. I have `C-s` bound to `helm-occur`, so I can search through this buffer with a helm-like interface as well. Also, in the `*Packages*` buffer, you can use `f` (`package-menu-filter`) which allows you to narrow down the package list based on a list of comma-separated keywords. However, I can understanding you wanting to avoid the aspects of `package-list-packages` outlined in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Install the `ido-ubiquitous` package and enable `(ido-ubiquitous-mode 1)`, and `(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)` to enable flex matching (not sure if that's necessary, but I have it set).  It basically makes all completion use ido, including `package-install`.  You can narrow with `C-SPC`, or use `<tab>` to pop up a completions buffer.

I usually use `list-packages`.  I use `flex-isearch` to automatically start flex matching after `isearch` either wraps around or has no matches.

Comment: Thanks jpkotta—I've gone with elethan's solution as I already have Helm installed and configured.

Answer (score 1):

According to a screenshot found [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html) there is such a thing as `M-x list-matching-lines` that does what you need (string search through packages.) I've tried it. The sequence of what was typed is shown in the screenshot. I didn't install anything special to get this functionality.

Comment: Better known as `M-x occur`, which is bound to `M-s o` by default.  `list-matching-lines` is an alias.

Answer (score 0):

1. `M-x package-install`
2. `ENTER`
3. Start typing the package you want to install (Eg: `xah-find`) and use the autocomplete option to select the package of your choice.

Credits: @elethan

Answer (score 0):

This performs search on package names and summaries:

```
(defun apropos-package--filter (string)
  (let (packages)
    (dolist (package-assoc package-archive-contents)
      (let ((package (cadr package-assoc)))
        (when (or (string-match-p (regexp-quote string) (package-desc-summary package))
                  (string-match-p (regexp-quote string) (prin1-to-string (package-desc-name package))))
          (push package packages))))
    packages))

(defun apropos-package (string)
  (interactive "sSearch for package: ")
  ;; Initialize the package system if necessary.
  (unless package--initialized
    (package-initialize t))
  (let ((packages (apropos-package--filter string)))
    (if (null packages)
    (message "No packages")
      (package-show-package-list (mapcar 'package-desc-name packages)))))
```

Invoke the command with `M-x apropos-package`